# Why is the gettext alias _() missing on OS X?

Tags: php, osx-lion

I'm running `OS X Lion` and some of my code uses the `gettext` alias of `_()` but I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function _()
```

Here is my env

```
PHP 5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 25 2011 10:41:21) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
      with Xdebug v2.1.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans
```

I tried using the php option `suhosin.simulation = On` but that didn't change anything so it doesn't seem to be the Suhosin-Patch.

Comment: What happens when you run `php --ri gettext`?

Comment: `Extension 'gettext' not present.` Doh! Now to install gettext.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the record... This is how you add `gettext` to `OS X Lion`

## Installing ICU

[Download ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/download/48#ICU4C-Download)

Run these commands

```
tar xzvf icu4c-4_8_1-src.tgz
cd icu/source
./runConfigureICU MacOSX
make
sudo make install
```

[Download PHP 5.3.6 sources](http://www.php.net/get/php-5.3.6.tar.gz/from/a/mirror)

Run these commands

```
tar -zxf php-5.3.6.tar.gz
cd ext/intl
phpize
./configure --enable-intl
make
sudo cp modules/intl.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
```

Put this in your php.ini file with

```
extension=intl.so
```

## Installing Gettext

[Download Gettext](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gettext/)

Run these commands

```
tar -zxf gettext-0.18.1.1.tar.gz
cd  gettext-0.18.1.1
```

> Apple will not ship Gettext and Intl the problem is that Gettext apparently defines Stpncpy function, as does something in Lion.

You need to open `gettext-tools/gnulib-lib/stpncpy.c` and change all references of `stpncpy` to `stpncpy2`

Then run these commands

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Go back to the PHP sources directory:

Run these commands

```
cd ext/gettext
phpize
./configure --with-gettext
make
sudo cp modules/gettext.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
```

And add this to the php.ini file:

```
extension=gettext.so
```

References:
http://www.ittreats.com/os/php/php-with-intl-and-gettext-on-osx-lion-bertrand-mansion.html

Answer (score 0):

I could install gettext a little bit simpler with the help from brew.

### Installing ICU

- brew install icu4c

### Installing gettext

- brew install gettext

### Building the modules

- Download php source from https://www.php.net/downloads.php

#### Building ICU module

> > export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin

> > ./configure --enable-intl LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include'

Maybe the LD/CPPFLAGS settings are not necessary.

#### Building gettext module

- Build gettext module with the ./configure script modification [./configure cannot locate header file when the directory is specified with CPPFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165067/configure-cannot-locate-header-file-when-the-directory-is-specified-with-cppfl)

> > ./configure --enable-gettext

#### Copy the generated modules

copy the modules to php libraries directory (/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-XXXXX).

#### Restart apache

`sudo apachectl restart`