# ./configure cannot locate header file when the directory is specified with CPPFLAGS

Tags: php, macos, unix, gettext, configure

I'm trying to build php gettext module on Mac OS X Mavericks.

Installed gettext with `brew install gettext`, and checked header files are available at `/usr/local/opt/gettext`.

```
$ ls /usr/local/opt/gettext/include/
autosprintf.h   gettext-po.h    libintl.h
```

With a help in the post of [How to override environment variables when running configure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717623/how-to-override-environment-variables-when-running-configure), I executed `./configure LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include/'` to get this error message.

```
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 0.13.6 (ok)
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for GNU gettext support... yes, shared
configure: error: Cannot locate header file libintl.h <--
```

What's wrong with this? Why configure cannot find the header file when I specified the directory?

Comment: How about `CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include/'` ?

Comment: @falsetru: I got a same error message with the CFLAGS setup.

Comment: While the linked answer says you can pass them as arguements to `configure` you might also want to try putting them *before* `./configure`. That is a typical Unix pattern of setting environment variables for one command run. So I suggest trying: `CPPFLAGS=blahblah ./configure`. If **that** doesn't work then try exporting the variable setting: `export CPPFLAGS=blahblah` and then run `./configure` after doing that. Hopefully one of these will do the trick.

Comment: @verdammelt: Unfortunately, none of the tricks worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into the ./configure script, I noticed the script doesn't look into the environmental variable that I give. I just modified the script (Line 4067) to get it work.

```
if test "$PHP_GETTEXT" != "no"; then
  for i in $PHP_GETTEXT /usr/local /usr /usr/local/opt/gettext; do
    test -r $i/include/libintl.h && GETTEXT_DIR=$i && break
  done
```

Answer (score 2):

When compiling php you can pass --with-gettext=/usr/local/opt/gettext as an option to the configure commmand - thats what sets the $PHP_GETTEXT variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the directory that introduces files generally in '/usr/include'

```
if test -f "/usr/include/WeWorkFinanceSdk_C.h" && test -f 
"/usr/include/libWeWorkFinanceSdk_C.so"; then
AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)
else
 AC_MSG_ERROR(cannot find WeWorkFinanceSdk_C.h in path ${PHP_WXWORK_FINANCE_SDK})
fi
```